# High quality plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I try plot some time series in high quality but matplotlib fails to save the figures in high quality. In the plotting the output looks like in the picture below, which is a screenshot.[image: Picture 1]

But using plt.safefig() or the save button gives me the following result[image: Picture]

The core of the problem is that I have to save plots using the png-backend. Safing as pdf, a file is created, which can not be opened by other apps. Even though the files are < 500 kb. The same happens when safing as .eps. My code is like:

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=True, ylim=(-1,1))
ax.plot(sig_obj, '-k', alpha=.3)
# plot of vertical lines ...
plt.savefig('figure_1.png')    # or .pdf
```

where `sig_obj` is an array of length > 350000. Using Python 3.4 and matplotlib 1.3.3 on OS X 10.9.4.

Does anyone have an idea to improve my plot quality?

Comment: By _"high quality"_, do you mean the different shades of grey that all seem to be the same in the second plot (alpha?)? Also note that there is no _"png-backend"_. [Click here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for a list of possibilities. You might want to check the ones that can produce PNGs, if they produce your desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either set a high dpi for a raster image:

```
savefig("1.png", dpi=600)
```

or save it in a vector format:

```
savefig("1.svg") # or: "1.pdf" (depending on a backend)
```